# Kentico ScriptHelper.RegisterScriptFile is not sending javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I have a basic page in Kentico v8 and I need to register some javascript. I have the following code in page_load event of web user control

```
ScriptHelper.RegisterScriptFile(Page, "~/CMSScripts/Mysite/Shared/Myjs.js");
```

The Myjs.js file is present in CMS/CMSScripts/MySite/Shared folder and other parts of the user control but the javascript does not appear to load. What could I be missing..

Here is full code for my ascx file

```
using System;
using CMS.Helpers;

namespace Aon.Exchange.Web.CMSWebParts.AonExchange.SharedPopup
{
    public partial class SharedPopup : UserControlBase
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          string script =
            "alert('hi');";
    //ScriptHelper.RegisterClientScriptBlock(base.Page, typeof(string), "ApplyTrim", ScriptHelper.GetScript(script));
         // Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"text/javascript","<script src=\'~/CMSScripts/MySite/Shared/sharedPopupHeader.js\'><" + "/script>");
      ScriptHelper.RegisterScriptFile(Page, ResolveUrl("~/CMSScripts/MySite/Shared/SharedPopupHeader.js"));
       /* _ScriptManager.RegisterJSFile("~/CMSScripts/MySite/Shared/sharedPopupHeader.js");*/
}
```

Comment: You might follow best practices with placement of your script too and place it in `/CMSScripts/Custom/MySite/` so it is able to be exported as well as editable within the UI.  If this is scripts related specifically to a webpart then you need to place them in the `/CMSWebParts/SiteName/WepartCodeName_files` folder.  See the folder structure here: https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Export+folder+structure

Comment: What is the syntax to add a custom javascript file using this approach ?

Comment: @SofiaKhwaja You just create another directory in CMSScripts called Custom, then another with the name of your site, then you move your script file to this directory.  Personally, I've always stored our scripts in media galleries so they can be used in the staging module.  You'll incur a small performance hit, but it likely won't be noticeable.

Comment: @SofiaKhwaja Can you edit your question to include the rest of your Page_Load method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue before as well, and wound up having to register my scripts like this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"text/javascript","<script src=\"/CMSScripts/Mysite/Shared/Myjs.js\"><" + "/script>");
```

Comment: Judging by your updated question, there might be a couple of problems.  What seems most likely is that the script block is actually being served, but your URL might be incorrect since CMSScripts isn't in the home directory of the Kentico project in v8.  Another possible problem might have to do with IIS_USERS not having permissions to that directory, which should only happen if someone has altered the permissions to that directory since it's given access by default.  Are you certain that script block isn't being served at all and that you're not just getting a 403 or 404 error code?

Comment: Thanks for your response Jerreck. I moved my scripts to the 'Custom' folder in the CMSScripts location. Then I added the control called 'Javascript' from 'General' category and I was able to link the source file. I really appereciate your help on this question.

Comment: I recreated another site and I was able to get the code working as below    ScriptHelper.RegisterScriptFile(Page, "~/CMSScripts/AonExchange/MySite/SharedPopupHeader.js");